Can't install tensorrt
No matter which I've done, I can't seem to install tensorrt.
I'm on Manjaro, and installed cuda and cudnn using pacman.  I'm attempting to install tensorrt from AUR (via sudo pamac install tensorrt) but get the following error:
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/Internal/CMakeCUDAFindToolkit.cmake:104 (message):
  Failed to find nvcc.

  Compiler requires the CUDA toolkit.  Please set the CUDAToolkit_ROOT
  variable.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeDetermineCUDACompiler.cmake:85 (cmake_cuda_find_toolkit)
  CMakeLists.txt:68 (project)

nvcc is in my $PATH:
$ which nvcc
/opt/cuda/bin/nvcc

I tried following the instructions here to set the appropriate environment variables (CUDACXX, CUDA_PATH, etc.) but none of them seemed to make a difference.
Just as a hack I edited the code in CMakeCUDAFindToolkit.cmake just above the error on line 104 to force it to use /opt/cuda/ in place of /usr/local/cuda.
Running again resulted in this error:
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeDetermineCUDACompiler.cmake:266 (message):
  Failed to detect a default CUDA architecture.



  Compiler output:

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:68 (project)

Clearly my hacky attempt there did not matter.  There is clearly something awry here, but I have no idea what it could possibly be.
